# Trying (and failing) to define a Dictionary which uses Tuples for Keys, and ArrayLists for Values

Tags: powershell, dictionary, arraylist

I've tried using the following code to set up a new Dictionary in my Powershell code. I want the Dictionary to use a tuple as the key, and an Arraylist as the value (so that I can add items to the value over time).

```
# Create dictionary
$mydict = [Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[Tuple[int,int]],Collections.ArrayList]]::new()
# Add an empty Arraylist to a key
$mydict.Add([Tuple]::Create(0,0),[Collections.ArrayList]::new())
# Try to add an item to this new arraylist
$mydict[(0,0)].Add(1)
MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."
# And sure enough:
$mydict[(0,0)].IsFixedSize
True
$mydict[(0,0)].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Anyone know why Powershell is ignoring my requests to add ArrayLists as members, and for some reason silently converting the objects to System.Array instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you used `[Tuple]::Create(0,0)`, i.e *explicit* creation of a tuple in the `.Add()` call, you must use the same in trying to *access* an entry:

```bash
$null = $mydict[[Tuple]::Create(0,0)].Add(1)
```

The reason that `(0,0)` didn't work as a lookup key is that it is of type `[object[]]` and PowerShell's [index operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#index-operator--) (`[…]`) by design supports passing an *array* of indices, whose *elements* are *individually* interpreted as indices to look up.

- E.g., `(1, 2, 3, 4)[1, -1]` yields `2, 4`, i.e. the second (`1`) and the last (`-1`) element of the input array.
- Since the `[object[]]` type of `(0, 0)` didn't match the actual key type of `$mydict`, `$mydict` was in effect treated like a *single-element array*, it was something *akin to* the [intrinsic array indexing of scalar types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#array-indexing-scalar-types)<sup>[1]</sup> that kicked in, meaning that both instances of `0` returned the `$mydict` dictionary *as a whole*, implicitly resulting in a *two-element array* to which the `.Add()` method was applied, and - because a .NET *array* (whose base type is always [`System.Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array)) is of *fixed size* - the `Collection was of a fixed size.` error was emitted.

---

<sup>[1] Note that PowerShell generally treats objects that implement the [`System.Collections.IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IDictionary) interface *as single objects* (scalars) in its pipeline, even though they *are* enumerable, namely as key-value pairs. However, with a *key type* that is an implementation of [`System.Collections.ICollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ICollection) *other than an array*, such as [`` System.Tuple`2 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Tuple-2) in your case, numeric indices, which on their own do *not* match such a key type, seemingly treat the dictionary instance like a *single-element array* when intrinsic indexing is applied, so that even *multiple* indices can be applied, and each index with value `0` or `-1` (to select the one and only "element" from the start or the end) returns the dictionary itself.</sup>

Comment: Perfect - thanks for the explanation!

Comment: ah yes - the follow up helps me understand why I didn't see a type error when I used the incorrect key type, and makes perfect sense why it returned a fixed size array now. Wonderful work!